# Can I initialize a PDA within a CPI call?

Tags: pda, cpi, initialize

I have a ProgramA and a ProgramB. ProgramB has an instruction "InstructionB" that initializes a PDA. If I try to call InstructionB from ProgramA with CPI, I get a "signer privilege escalated" error.

Is it possible to perform the PDA initialization that is contained in an instruction that I want to call as a CPI?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, what you're doing is possible, the problem is that there is some address that you need to pass as a signer.

Your "InstructionB" specifies an address as payer for the PDA creation. This is the likely culprit.